# Saving a file as a string in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am building a web application using Node.js, Backbone.js, and Mongo.  This application will allow the user to upload a DXF file to the server so that the file can be "parsed" to extract geometrical information about a building structure.  I am trying to decide how to store this dxf file on the server.

Is there any benefit to storing the file as a large string in Mongodb vs just storing the file on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is only needed long enough for it to be parsed, and you spawn a child process to do this (if an external binary is needed or even just to insulate the initial process), then you shouldn't need to store it in Mongo.

On the other hand, if there is any chance that your application will be working across more than one webserver, and more than one will need access to the data, then it's a good idea to throw it into Mongo.

In an ideal world, DXF would be streamable, and a Node library could be coded to accept an input stream piped from a request.

Comment: I use the dxf file to build a highly nested, method intense (numerical  analysis of structures...beams, columns, footings) Object.  Each time the user want to analyse say a beam, the file will need to be parsed and the "Project" object constructed; it is this object that has all the methods.

Comment: I understand that I could put the data from the dxf file into the database and then write a new BuildProject function.  But this is a substantial amount of work and I'm wondering if the payoff would be worth it.  I'm currently using npm's "Buffertools" to parse the dxf file although I mostly fumbled through it not really understanding buffers...

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is computationally expensive. A better solution would be to parse the file once and store the *result* in Mongo.

I'm loathe to say this, but you may want to consider using mongoose or some other ORM if you are pressed for time. That way you can store your objects and reliably load them from the datastore, and you can keep all the methods seamlessly.

Comment: That said, storing an object is not so hard, and modifying your constructor function to take a key in the db (loading) and giving it a static method to parse an input (decoding DXF) string would be simple to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "store it as a large string" in a MongoDB document because there is a limit on the document size.

Either use GridFS or store it in the file system and keep a reference to it in the database.

Comment: I guess what a "large string" is is debatable.  The Dxf files that I'll be using are small enough to store in mongo.  I like your idea about storing a reference to the file location in the db...thanks